# Can't make rollup bundle memfs package for browser; Getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined"

Tags: javascript, rollupjs

I was trying to compile [memfs package](https://github.com/streamich/memfs/) for the browser. Webpack build is working just fine, but I want to bundle it with rollup and I constanlty getting `"Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined"`.

I've made [repl.it example with my config](https://replit.com/@smertelny/rollup-commonjs-question)

For someone who do not wanna use repl.it, here are my files:

```
// rollup.config.js

import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve"
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs"
import nodePolyfills from "rollup-plugin-polyfill-node";

export default {
    input: 'index.js',
    output: {
        dir: "dist",
        format: 'esm',
    },
    plugins:[
        nodePolyfills(),
        resolve({
            preferBuiltins: false,
            browser: true,
        }),
        commonjs(),
    ],
}
```

File I am trying to process:

```
// index.js
import { fs } from "memfs";

let code = `
  console.log("hello, world!");
`;

fs.writeFileSync("./code", code);

console.log(fs.readFileSync("./code"));
```

I've tried many `commonjs` options and nothing worked for me.
Maybe I am missing something?

Thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've figured it out. I've had a wrong plugin order.

The right order is:

```
export default {
    // all previous settings
    plugins: [
        resolve({
            preferBuiltins: false,
            browser: true,
        }),
        commonjs(),
        nodePolyfills(),
    ]
};
```